# Xamarin.Forms Shell Tabs only showing last Tab in the list

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am migrating my existing code to Xamarin Forms 4.0 `Shell`, Previously I was using `TabbedPage` but now I want to use `Shell` Tabs.

Below is what the code looks like after migration. What I noticed is that it's only showing one top tab which has last entry in the list. In my case, it's showing Tab2 only.

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      xmlns:views="clr-namespace:App.Views.Tabs;assembly=App"
      x:Class="App.Views.AppShell"
      x:Name="self">
  <TabBar>
       <Tab>
            <ShellContent>
              <views:Tab1Page BindingContext="{x:Reference self}" Title="Tab1" />
              <views:Tab2Page BindingContext="{x:Reference self}" Title="Tab2"/>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
   </TabBar>
   
</Shell>
```

Comment: Do you want to see both tabs on top.

Comment: Put each ContentPage inside `<tab>` tag

Comment: @mshwf Putting ContentPage inside separate `<tab>` is giving me bottom tabs. instead, I need tabs at the top.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

```
<Shell>
...   
   <Tab>
        <ShellContent Title="Tab1">  <!-- title in the tab -->
            <views:Tab1Page} Title="Tab1" BindingContext="{x:Reference self}"/>
                        <!-- Title in the navigation bar -->
        </ShellContent>
        
        <ShellContent Title="Tab2">
            <views:Tab2Page} Title="Tab2" BindingContext="{x:Reference self}"/>
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
...
</Shell>
```

#### Microsoft Documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs